# program breaks when allocating dynamic memory to store copy of string

Tags: c++, string, memory

I am trying to see if all of my functions work correctly and the program runs to black screen and it closes and it gives me an error with yellow triangle exclammation mark inside the triangle saying that

"Exception thrown 0x01971FD0 (ucrtbased.dll) in milestone2.exe 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000"

arrow indicating .cpp file  **m_message = new char [strlen(str) + 1 ]** located at void ErrorMessage::message(const char* str) at

im guessing it is some kind of memory issue, anyone knows the solution?

**Header file**

```
#ifndef SICT_ERROR_H_
#define SICT_ERROR_H_
namespace sict {
    class ErrorMessage {
        char* m_message;
    public:

        ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage = nullptr);
        ErrorMessage(const ErrorMessage& em) = delete;
        ErrorMessage& operator=(const ErrorMessage& em) = delete;
        virtual ~ErrorMessage();
        void clear();
        bool isClear() const;
        void message(const char* str);
        const char* message() const;
    };
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, ErrorMessage);
}
#endif
```

**Cpp file**

```
#include "ErrorMessage.h"
#include <iostream>
namespace sict {

    ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage) {
        m_message = nullptr;
        message(errorMessage);
    }
    void ErrorMessage::clear() {
        delete[] m_message;
        m_message = nullptr;
    }
    void ErrorMessage::message(const char* str) {
        delete[] m_message;
        m_message = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy(m_message, str);
    }
    const char* ErrorMessage::message() const {
        return m_message;
    }
    ErrorMessage::~ErrorMessage() {
        clear();
    }
    bool ErrorMessage::isClear() const {
        if (m_message == nullptr) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, ErrorMessage error) {
        if (!(error.isClear())) {
            ostr << error.message();
        }
        return ostr;
    }


}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ErrorMessage.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sict;

int main() {
    ErrorMessage T("Testing Error Message Module");
    ErrorMessage e;
    int ret = 0;
    bool ok = true;
    cout << T << endl << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Passed!" : "Failed!") << endl;
    if (!e.isClear()) ok = false;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "===========| Long Message\r";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        if (i % 1000000 == 0) {
            cout << "*";
            cout.flush();
        }
        e.message("Some error message that is really long long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long"
            " long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long  long");
    }
    cout << '*' << endl;
    cout << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Failed!" : "Passed!") << endl;
    if (e.isClear()) ok = false;
    cout << endl;

    e.message("Short Message");
    cout << e << endl << e.message() << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Failed!" : "Passed!") << endl;
    if (e.isClear()) ok = false;

    e.clear();
    cout << e << endl << "isClear(): " << (e.isClear() ? "Passed!" : "Failed!") << endl;
    if (!e.isClear()) ok = false;
    cout << endl;

    if (ok) {
        cout << "You passed all the tests!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "You did not pass all the tests" << endl;
        ret = 1;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger and trace the execution of the `ErrorMessage` default constructor.

Comment: how do i do that if i may ask?

Comment: That depends on your platform and IDE.  This article on [how to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is frequently mentioned..

Comment: It's usually a very good idea to stay away from C, i.e. plain `char*` strings and C-API like `strlen`. Why do you not use `std::string`? It will also simplify the code significantly, e.g. release resources automatically. If you are a C programmer, it may be better to erase parts of your memory :-)

Answer (score 3):

In your main() you have:

```
ErrorMessage e;
```

Which will call your constructor with a null pointer:

```
ErrorMessage::ErrorMessage(const char* errorMessage) {
    m_message = nullptr;
    message(errorMessage);
}
```

Your constructor will then call message() and pass that null pointer to it:

```
void ErrorMessage::message(const char* str) {
    delete[] m_message;
    m_message = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    strcpy(m_message, str);
}
```

Hence, you are trying to do strlen() on a null pointer. This is why it's giving segfault.

Comment: oh thank you!, So the reason was because the message was set to nullptr which created problem. I made if statement in message void function and now it works